# XML File not Neat

Tags: xml, ruby-on-rails-2

Please could anyone tell me the reason for this. I have a create_file action in my controller.

```
   file = File.new("xml/experiment.xml", "w") 
   # creating the builder file for the xml
   xml = Builder::XmlMarkup.new :target => file
   # xml tags 
   xml.instruct! 
   xml.EXPERIMENT_SET { 
   xml.alias("#{@experiment.alias}") 
   xml.center_name "#{@experiment.center_name}"
   }
```

I get an output like this.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><EXPERIMENT_SET><alias>ZAP430</alias><center_name></center_name></EXPERIMENT_‌​SET>
```

Which is not a neat XML, all tags are displayed in a single line.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316020/rails-xml-builder-with-no-pretty-printing-i-e-minified-xml

Comment: thanks for the reply Tichodroma. but unfortunately I could not figure out the solution. Please could you show me what to do in my code, I am a newbie in ROR.

removing :target => file also does not help, neither does :indent => 2 works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the parameter `:indent` while creating your instance of `XmlMarkup`.

From the documentation of `[Builder::XmlMarkup][1]`:

```
xm = Builder.new(:indent=>2)
# xm will produce nicely formatted and indented XML.

xm = Builder.new(:indent=>2, :margin=>4)
# xm will produce nicely formatted and indented XML with 2
# spaces per indent and an over all indentation level of 4.

builder = Builder::XmlMarkup.new(:target=>$stdout, :indent=>2)
builder.name { |b| b.first("Jim"); b.last("Weirich) }
# prints:
#     <name>
#       <first>Jim</first>
#       <last>Weirich</last>
#     </name>
```

Comment: Thank you so very much Tichodroma. It worked perfectly fine. Appreciate your help.
Cheers

Comment: Tichodroma, Please could you tell me if I could render a partial or something like that for the xml tags alone, I am basically creating several xml files in one go from a single action and I would like to know if there could be any way where I could keep the controller short and clean. Appreciate your suggestions. Cheers